# How to mention times before?

Tags: time

Which form is better for mentioning a time before :

- a month and ten days ago
- ten days and a month ago
- one month and ten days ago
- ten days and a month ago

Comment: Two of those options are the same. How about "six weeks ago"? That's far more idiomatic.

Comment: No.2 and No.4 are identical, perhaps you meant to write: *ten days and one month ago.*

Comment: @AndrewLeach I want to be exact.

Comment: Surely in that case, it's an exact number of days, since "a month" can vary.

Comment: If you want to be exact, then say "40 days ago", or however many it's been, exactly.

Comment: Five weeks and three (or four or five) days.

Comment: @Engli5h Could you edit the question to make it clear exactly what you want to achieve here? Otherwise we're just amassing comments. Hopefully there's been enough clarification here to allow the question to be fully defined.

Comment: I believe OP's questions are:  Is it **a** month or **one** month and do you list the months first and then the days or the other way 'round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more idiomatic (and not just in English) to go from biggest to smallest. You are much more likely to encounter "ten years, five months and three days ago" than "three days, five months, and ten years ago". Both are equally grammatical, though. The latter is just quite unusual, but that in turn allows you to use it on purpose for an effect.

Likewise for *a month ago* vs. *one month ago*. Both are equally grammatical, but the former is more common. Indeed, the [Corpus of Contemporaty American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) has 1432 cites for the former, but only 88 for the latter, and the [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) has 212 and 4, respectively. However, I think depending on the context, the latter might have a connotation of being more specific, not entirely unlike "a couple days ago" vs. "two days ago".